# how to prevent entity framework to change column names of just one of tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, model, ef-database-first

i have column names with "underline" in the names,
when in update model from database entity frame work remove "underline" in the names,
i use jsonPropertyName annotation for fix this issue , but when i update agin,json jsonPropertyNames remove.

```
            entity.Property(e => e.DesChkHecli)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .HasColumnName("DES_CHK_HECLI");
```

how can prevent to change column name?

Comment: could you try using this code: `[Column("DES_CHK_HECLI")]
   public string DesChkHecli { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework by default uses column name with underscore for relational tables. For example CategoryId in Products table will be named as Category_ID. Maybe you can use `[Column("DES_CHK_HECLI")]` attribute upper of your property. Then add migration again. I hope it will help.